# Как сделать группировку по результату агрегатной функции

Tags: sql, postgresql

Предположим есть две табица "человек", которая имеет отношение один-ко-многим к таблице "рука". У таблицы "человек" есть столбец  "имя".

Нужно вычислить статистику по количеству рук для разных имён людей.
Для этого я пишу запрос:

```
SELECT "человек"."имя",
       COUNT(DISTINCT "рука"."id") AS "количество_рук",
       COUNT(DISTINCT "рука"."id") AS "общее_количество_рук"
FROM "человек"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "рука" ON ("человек"."id" = "рука"."человек_id")
GROUP BY количество_рук, "человек"."имя"
ORDER BY количество_рук ASC, "человек"."имя" ASC
```

Ожидаю получить такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, в GROUP BY нельзя использовать алиас. Как правильно написать запрос, чтобы получить результат как на картинке?

Comment: Не совсем понял разницы между «количеством рук» и «общим количеством рук». Поясните на словах, пожалуйста.

Comment: @AndrewNikolaev, первое - это количество рук с группировкой, оно группирует результаты по вариантам, а вариантов возможных три: 0,1,2. А общее количество рук - это общее их количество для данной строки.